# Order "Items to ship" not displaying items cannot submit shipment

Tags: orders, shipping, cache, redis, magento-1.9

Having a problem with orders where if I select an order & then go to the ship page it does not display the product at the bottom & I cannot submit shipment.
Was ok until I turned off Redis cache & went back to Magento cache because of a separate problem.  Flushed Magento cache, logged out/in, deleted var/cache & var/sessions, turned Redis back on but still the same.
Cant seem to find anything similar so could really do with some help.
Thanks

Any One?

Comment: Do you have a dev environment to check on this?

Comment: No but have another site set more or less the same & I disabled the Redis cache on that & it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation it was an overriding module Raveinfosys_Exporter that was causing the issues. Disabling the module fixed the issue. 
http://www.raveinfosys.com/business-it-services/e-commerce-applications/magento-services/bulk-import-export-orders-to-csv/
`
        
            
                Raveinfosys_Exporter_Block

```
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_shipment_view_form>Raveinfosys_Exporter_Block_Sales_Order_Form_Form</sales_order_shipment_view_form>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>

        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_shipment_create_items>Raveinfosys_Exporter_Block_Sales_Order_Items</sales_order_shipment_create_items>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>

    </blocks>
```

`